# Using the same form for user insertion and update in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have the user, which can register via form: name, lastname, email, phone, password, username.

Registered user can change: name, lastname, phone

My UserType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('lastname', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('phone', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'text')
        ->add('username', 'text');
}
```

How should I render different form for registration and update?

Comment: Simple: just make another `Twig` view and inject the same `FormType` but only display `form_row()` that are needed. You'd need to bind your form with your entity though so data is present in the form when user is changing their profile.

Answer (score 1):

Only difference is what you pass as a second attribute to `createForm` method. If you pass empty entity it will be form to add new user. If you pass entity with populated data of your user entity it will be an edit form. So:

```
$yourNewUserForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), new UserEntity());

$userEntity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:User')->find(1);
$yourEditUserForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $userEntity);
```

**NOTE:** Above code assumes you are in class extending `Controller` and you have your `createForm` and `getDoctrine()` methods available but consider if this should be a part of controller or it should be moved somewhere else (which is probably a better idea)